# How to test JavaScript libraries using a testing tool?

Tags: testing, browser, cross-browser

I am looking for a testing tool that helps to test JavaScript libraries in any OS or browser. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

The Yahoo UI Test tools ( http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/yuitest/ ) allow you to write unit tests for your JavaScript. You can then run the tests in all the browsers you need to.

If you want to test the interaction of the JavaScript with the UI/DOM, etc then something like Selinium ( http://seleniumhq.org/ ) allows you to record tests like macros inside a browser and replay them in most browser on several different operating systems using their Java client.